# Case Insensitive Dictionary Iteration

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which has peoples' first names as keys. Each name has a capitalised first letter (James, Ben, John, etc).

I use list comprehension to check if any keys are in a string:

```
[val for key, val in name_dict.items() if key in new_message]
```

The issue is that sometimes the names appear in new_message without capitalised first letters (james, ben, john, etc). I could add these variations to the dictionary but that sould invovle a lot of work.

Is there a simple way to iterate over the dictionary keys in a case insensitive way?

Comment: `if key.lower() == new_message.lower()`?

Comment: `==` won't work here, `if key.lower() in new_message.lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just lower the text while iterating,

```
new_message = [x.lower() for x in new_message]
[val for key, val in name_dict.items() if key.lower() in new_message]
```

( Assuming if the new_message is list, for string it will be just `new_message.lower()` )
This will make the comparison case-insensitive.

Full example

```
>>> new_message = ['John', 'JameS', 'BEN']
>>> name_dict = {'john': 1, 'Ben': 2, 'JaMES': 3}
>>> 
>>> [x.lower() for x in new_message]
['john', 'james', 'ben']
>>> new_message = [x.lower() for x in new_message]
>>> [val for key, val in name_dict.items() if key.lower() in new_message]
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `title()` on `new_message`, it will capitalize all the words in the string

```
new_message = 'James, ben, JOHN'
print(new_message.title()) # James, Ben, John
```

Comment: it will be better to user `.lower()` on the `key` and on the `new_message`

Comment: it will cover more options

Comment: @OmerDagry The dictionary contains only names in a known (capitalized) format, it's not necessary.